# How to display a message after submitting the review in Woocommerce?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and I have to show a message after submitting the review on the product.

wc_add_notice('Thank you for submitting the review. Your review is awaiting approval.');

Any idea how to display messages after submitting review?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comment_post` action hook. you need to check the comment belongs to a `product` and the comment type is `review` or it will be applied to all comments in all post types.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'review_submit_notice', 100, 3 );

function review_submit_notice( $comment_id, $is_approved, $commentdata ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ( 'product' === get_post_type( absint( $commentdata['comment_post_ID'] ) ) ) && ( 'review' === $commentdata['comment_type'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice('Thank you for submitting the review. Your review is awaiting approval.');
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I am not getting any alerts.

Comment: Does it work? I need to try

Answer (score -1):

You can use `comment_post_redirect` filter hook and inside that hook you can use `wc_add_notice` function. check below code. code will go in your active theme `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'show_notice_after_review_submit', 99 );
function show_notice_after_review_submit( $location ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Thank you for submitting the review. Your review is awaiting approval.', 'woocommerce' ), 'success' );
    return $location;
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Give me some time to check this answer.

Comment: I tried twice but I am not getting this message.

Comment: I have added at the bottom of my theme->function.php.

Comment: I tried updated answers but still not showing.

Comment: @user9437856 Which theme are you using?

Comment: This is the custom theme created. But I am getting all the alerts except this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230753/discussion-between-bhautik-and-user9437856).